# Main calling too many classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having some unexpected results when writing a program. I have three classes and they all compile properly, but when I runt them, they do not seem to write the proper output to the console. Based on my main method, I should get a result showing:

```
Extender called
ClassTest called
```

However, it is writing:

```
AbsClass called
Extender called
ClassTest called
```

I use a `super()` in the ClassTest class constructor, but that should only call the parent class, right?

Here's the first class:

```
public abstract class AbsClass {
    public AbsClass() {
        System.out.println("AbsClass called");
    }        
}
```

Here's the second class:

```
public class Extender extends AbsClass {
    public Extender() {
        System.out.println("Extender called");
    }
}
```

Here's the last class with the main method:

```
public class ClassTest extends Extender {
    public ClassTest() {
        super();
        System.out.println("ClassTest called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassTest test = null;
        test=new ClassTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: I'm getting you expected result.... what's the wrong ? Do you know how to Compile & run java ?

Comment: @Suzon I know how to compile and run, but I am getting the latter result I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

If you have inherited classes, constructor IS ALWAYS called for all ancestors.

If you dont specify it with `super(parameters)`, then `super()` is called by default.

Note that code become uncompilable, if ancestor have constructors with parameters and do not have one without parameters and its extended class do not specify which constructor he wants to call.

Example :

```
public abstract class AbsClass {
    public AbsClass(String text) {
        System.out.println("AbsClass called: " + text);
    }        
}

public class Extender extends AbsClass {
    public Extender() {
        System.out.println("Extender called");
    }
}
```

Is not compilable.

(Important thing : If class does not have constructor, there is implicitly auto-created constructor which takes no parameters)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a constructor that does not start with an explicit call to `this()` or `super()`, then the compiler automatically inserts a call to the default superclass constructor. From the [Java Language Specification (§8.8.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Thus, the default constructor `AbsClass()` is called when the constructor for `Extender` starts executing.